# selenium python xpath trouble finding element text() on page

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, text

I'm trying to verify the text `Active:` from this example

```
<div class="details">
    <p class="double">
        <a href="url">Set as default</a>
        <br>
        <a id="modal124434" class="modalAction" href="#">Delete</a>
    </p>
    <span class="bold">TEXT</span>
    : 1234567890 (12/2017)
    <br>
    Active:
    <a class="game" href="#GAME">GAME</a>
</div>
```

I also need to check `TEXT` to make sure it's there. I used the following to find `TEXT`:

```
foo = b.find_element_by_xpath('//span[contains(text(),"TEXT")]/..')
```

and when I `print(foo.text)` I can see all the text from the html example abve. So, I thought I could do something like this:

```
b.find_element_by_xpath('//span[contains(text(),"TEXT")]/..[contains(text(),"Active:")]/a[text()="GAME"]
```

but I get a NoSuchElement exception. I've also tried:

```
b.find_element_by_xpath('//*[contains(text(),"Active")]')
```

and still got nothing. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: In this example, the text you are after is between two elements. Perhaps the answer here will be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15813903/how-to-select-text-between-two-nodes

Comment: Which `text` are you trying to locate exactly? **TEXT** or **Active:** or **GAME**?

Comment: Do you need to get substring `"Active:"` from node or you need to locate element by substrings `"TEXT"` and `"Active:"`?

Comment: @debanjanbI and @Andersson was hoping to verify the text of all three in one xpath if possible.
@Tim So once I've found the `text()[2]` how can I tell what text is in that element?

Comment: So it turns out for what I'm doing I don't actually need to verify the `Active:` text, because the `<a>` that has `GAME` in it will not appear if `Active:` isn't present. So I was able to use `'//span[contains(.,"TEXT")]/../a[text()="GAME"]'`

Comment: I am still interested if it is possible to solve my original issue though.

Comment: Coming back to this, I have figured out a way to do what I originally wanted. I've posted my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coming back to this I was able to find a way to do what I originally wanted

```
b.find_element_by_xpath('//span[contains(text(),"TEXT")]/..[contains(.,"Active:")]/a[text()="GAME"]')
```

it seems like using `text()` only looks into the first textNode that appears on that web element. but using `.` looks at all textNodes of that element as well as any textNodes that are attached to any childNode "beneath" the current element.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this xpath :- `//span/following-sibling::text()[2]`

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span/following-sibling::text()[2]").text   ;

Comment: once I've found the `text()[2]` how can I tell what text is in that element?

Comment: I get an exception when trying this `selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: TypeError: Argument 1 of Window.getComputedStyle does not implement interface Element.`

Comment: I ended up using part of your answer for the work around that I used for this. I recently realized that I never posted my work around.

I used the following xpath:
'//span[text()="TEXT"]/following-sibling::a[text()="GAME"]'

Answer (score 1):

To print the element texts  **TEXT**, **Active:** and **GAME** you can use the following code blocks :

- To print **`TEXT`** :

  ```
  print(b.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='details']//span[@class='bold']").get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- To print **`Active:`** :

  ```
  fullsting = b.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='details']").get_attribute("innerHTML")
  part_word = fullsting.split(")")
  words = part_word[1].split("G")
  print(words[0])
  ```
- To print **`GAME`** :

  ```
  print(b.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='details']//a[@class='game']").get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```

Comment: The `innerHTML` attribute is cool, I did not know about that, but I was hoping to use one xpath string to verify all three of these items at once.

Comment: @DanielWillemin Nice to know that. Did your Question get answered?

Comment: Sadly no, I did find a work around not involving the text `Active:` though.

Comment: Coming back to this, I have figured out a way to do what I originally wanted. I've posted my answer.